# Html Table is not vewing before Read more

Tags: php, html, twig

what i need.

- i need table should viewed before read more.

1 . snapshot before (no html table is viewed before the read more).

[image]

2. snapshot after on clicking read more .( on clicking read more another table is viewed).

[image]
php code

```
                            {% for key,value in data.result %}

                            {# set comments=value.metadata.comment #}
                            {% set metadata= value.metadata|length %}
                            {% set comments= value.metadata[0].comment|length %}
                            {% set comments_flag = comments_flag + value.metadata|length%}
                            {% if comments_flag > 7 and reminder_flag==0 %}
                            {% set reminder_flag=1 %}
                            {% set comments_flag=0 %}
                            {% set comments_flag = comments_flag + value.metadata|length %}

                            {% endif %}


                            {% if metadata > 1 and metadata!=2 %}
                            {%if reminder_flag ==1%}
                            </table>
                            <span  id ="feesmorere" class="more" onclick="$('#feesmore').show();$('#feesmorere').hide();">+ Read more</span>
                            <table id ="feesmore" class="dis-non  tb not-mobile " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                            {% endif %}
                            {% if reminder_flag ==1 %}
                            <tr>
                            <td width="30%"  rowspan={{ metadata }} style="border-top:0px">{{ value.type }}</td>
                            {% set metadatas= value.metadata %}
                            {% for key,value in metadatas %}
                            <td width="58%" style="border-top:0px">{{ value.comment }}</td>
                            <td width="12%" class="aligncenter " style="border-top:0px">{{ curr}} {{ value.amount }} </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {%else %}

                            <tr>
                            <td width="30%"  rowspan={{ metadata }}>{{ value.type }}</td>
                            {% set metadatas= value.metadata %}
                            {% for key,value in metadatas %}
                            <td width="58%">{{ value.comment }}</td>
                            <td width="12%" class="aligncenter ">{{ curr}} {{ value.amount }} </td>

                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {%endif%}
```

array structure

```
    [0] => Array
      (
        [type] => Member
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 1350
                        [comment] => Early Bird RegistrationPricing Deadline14 August 2014 - See more at: http://congresses.pmi.org/NorthAmerica2014/Registration/#sthash.7X1yMZt6.dpuf
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 1650
                        [comment] => Early Bird RegistrationPricing Deadline14 August 2014 - See more at: http://congresses.pmi.org/NorthAmerica2014/Registration/#sthash.7X1yMZt6.dpuf
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 900
                        [comment] => Early Bird RegistrationPricing Deadline14 August 2014 - See more at: http://congresses.pmi.org/NorthAmerica2014/Registration/#sthash.7X1yMZt6.dpuf
                    )
        )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [type] => Non-Member
        [metadata] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 1450
                        [comment] => On-site RegistrationPricing Begins15 August 2014
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 1750
                        [comment] => On-site RegistrationPricing Begins15 August 2014
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [amount] => 1100
                        [comment] => On-site RegistrationPricing Begins15 August 2014
                    )
```

- problem im having no html table is viewed before read more.
- i have tried with

  ```
   {% if comments_flag > 7 and reminder_flag==0  and  key!=1 %}.
  ```
- works fine while using this conditions.
- but not working for another conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? add a function to the top of your html or better still to a linked js file , then just call it with the onclick rather than trying to code inside the button onclick.

```js
   
   function toshow(){
     $('#feesmore').toggle();
     $('#feesmorere').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="feesmorere" class="more" onclick="toshow()" >
   + Read more</span> 
<div id="feesmore" style="display:none;" onclick="toshow()">Fees more Table</div>
```